# Laravel open db file extension

Tags: php, laravel

I can't open a database with PDO on Laravel. Here is my example what it works without Laravel framework on a simple PHP file and on framework don't want to work.

That is the simple php file without Laravel:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:filename.DB');
$statement = $pdo->query("select * from test");
$result = $statement ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That is how I try to get the same result with Laravel:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use PDO;
class Teszt extends Controller {
    public function teszt(){
        $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:filename.db');
        $statement = $pdo->query("select * from test");
        $result = $statement ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        dump($result);
    }
}
```

On image is the error. I have the table logs on that database:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exOkX.png)
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCL9n.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/SYNOSYSLOGDB__ARCH.db");
```